# make view modes for commerce enabled by default when exporting with features

Tags: commerce, features, entities

I am trying to make the Drupal Commerce view modes administrator and checkout_pane enabled by default when I export with features.

I have strongarm dependency required; but I do not see the view mode options available.

Does anyone have some ideas? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

That info is stored in the `field_bundle_settings_node__contenttypenamehere` variable.  So make sure you export that for each of your content types.